# Why NSMutableArray doesn't get sorted?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsmutablearray

```
NSFileManager *fileManager= [[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *myEnumerator= [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:[[theFolder URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]path]];
    int f,size=0;
    NSMutableArray *dirList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *fpath;
    while (fpath=[myEnumerator nextObject])
    {
        [dirList addObject:fpath];

    }
    [dirList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

dirList contains filenames like "name_0012345.tif". Despite the sort the array doesn't contain the file in the order i would see in the finder sorting by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` is actually an `NSArray` method that returns a *new* sorted array (which you promptly ignore). You mean to use `-sortUsingSelector:`, which is an `NSMutableArray` method that rearranges the existing array itself.

It's pretty common in Cocoa to have one method for returning a modified immutable version of an object, and another method for modifying the mutable object itself (`-stringByAppendingString:` and `-appendString:`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

From [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector%3a)
`sortedArrayUsingSelector:`
**Returns an array** that lists the receiving array’s elements in ascending order, as determined by the comparison method specified by a given selector.